# Problems with same page scroll plugin in django-cms

Tags: django-cms

I need to make a same-page scroll design with links on a sidebar that scrollto anchors for different sections within the same page.

I am trying to use the [cmsplugin-sections](https://github.com/mkoistinen/cmsplugin-sections) and run into a *'NoneType' object is not iterable error* when trying to add a section container. Someone opened an identical [issue](https://github.com/mkoistinen/cmsplugin-sections/issues/6) too on the same subject a few days ago. Below the trace:

Any help most welcome as I am new to django-cms. MAybe another plugin with the same functionality? Basically I need an custom text plugin for each section which has a title field and a display menu title too.

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/?edit

Django Version: 1.8.9
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('djangocms_admin_style',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.sitemaps',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.messages',
'cms',
'menus',
'sekizai',
'treebeard',
'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
'djangocms_style',
'djangocms_column',
'djangocms_file',
'djangocms_googlemap',
'djangocms_inherit',
'djangocms_link',
'djangocms_picture',
'djangocms_teaser',
'djangocms_video',
'reversion',
'grounded_change',
'cmsplugin_sections')
Installed Middleware:
('cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware')

Template error:
In template /Users/user/templates/fullwidth.html, error at line 7
'NoneType' object is not iterable

1 : {% extends "base.html" %}

2 : {% load cms_tags %}

3 :

4 : {% block title %}{% page_attribute "page_title" %}{% endblock title %}

5 :

6 : {% block content %}

7 : {% placeholder "content" %}

8 : {% endblock content %}

9 :

Traceback:
File "/Users/user/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response

    response = response.render() File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
    return self.template.render(context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
    return self._render(context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
    return node.render(context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
    return node.render(context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/classytags/core.py" in render
    return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sekizai/templatetags/sekizai_tags.py" in render_tag
    rendered_contents = nodelist.render(context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
    return node.render(context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/classytags/core.py" in render
    return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py" in render_tag
    rendered_contents = nodelist.render(context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
    return node.render(context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
    return node.render(context) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/classytags/core.py" in render
    return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py" in render_tag
    content = get_placeholder_content(context, request, page, name, inherit, nodelist) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py" in get_placeholder_content
    content = render_placeholder(placeholder, context, name) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/plugin_rendering.py" in render_placeholder
    content.extend(render_plugins(plugins, context, placeholder, processors)) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/plugin_rendering.py" in render_plugins
    out.append(plugin.render_plugin(context, placeholder, processors=processors)) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pluginmodel.py" in render_plugin
    context = plugin.render(context, instance, placeholder_slot) File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/gc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmsplugin_sections/cms_plugins.py" in render
    for child in instance.child_plugin_instances:

Exception Type: TypeError at /en/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome this by:

1. Editing the cms_plugins.py file, basically adding an if statement before the for loops to check whether there is anything inside the section container to iterate
2. Running python manage.py migrate to create the tables (not mentioned in the installation instructions)